# Images not loading unless I rebuild App Next JS

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, next.js

I am having trouble with images lately in next js. I know next has deprecated support for static in favour of public directory. So even after refactoring, I still cant get images to load. Here is the flow:
I choose an image for a project and send an axios request to the server. The server only saves the path to mongodb like this:

```
  staticPath = `/ProjectImages/projImg_${req.decodedTokenData.userId}_${_id}_${key}.png`;
  let imagePath = path.normalize(__dirname + `/../../public${staticPath}`);
  dbImages.push(staticPath);
```

and writes the image's base64encoded value to a file and saves it to ProjectImages directory in public dir.
Now when I create a project, the images doesnt load even though it has reference to the path and the image itself is in the correct place. Only after rebuilding the app do I see the image.
Note: this issue does not occur in development mode only in production.
please help.!

Answer (score 1):

Masla he koi ni

rather than calling the images from source directly i would recommend you to create a route and serve all those images from there

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

router.get('/media/project/:path',function (req,res,next) {
    const _path = `/static/ProjectImages/${req.params.path}`;
    let imagePath = path.normalize(__dirname + `/../../public${_path}`);
    try{
        if (fs.existsSync(imagePath)) {
            res.sendFile(imagePath);
        }else{
            res.sendStatus(404);
        }
    }catch (err) {
        res.sendStatus(404);
    }
});
```